# Reading Xml File using DOM & storing it in Dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, dom

I have this Following XML File:

```
<Depts>
  <Dept Name="Admin">
    <Emps>
      <Emp>1</Emp>
      <Emp>8</Emp>
    </Emps>
  </Dept>
  <Dept Name="HR">
    <Emps>
      <Emp>3</Emp>
    </Emps>
  </Dept>
  <Dept Name="Operation">
    <Emps>
      <Emp>5</Emp>
      <Emp>9</Emp>
    </Emps>
  </Dept>
</Depts>
```

And I have written this program using DOM to read and store the data into dictionary. But, while printing I am not getting any output. The console remains Blank.

The code is below:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("Employee.xml");
XmlNodeList node1 = document.GetElementsByTagName("Dept Name");
foreach (var item in node1)
{
  XmlNodeList node2 = document.GetElementsByTagName("//Emps/Emp");
  foreach (var item1 in node2)
  {
    dictionary.Add(item.ToString(),Convert.ToInt32(item1.ToString()));
  }
}
foreach (var item in dictionary)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Key= " + item.Key + "\nValues= " + item.Value );
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What kind of output you are looking for? I mean how you want to store data in dictionary?

Comment: Use `document.SelectNodes("xpath")` instead of `GetElementsByTagName`, as you want to retrieve data from xml base on xpath.

Comment: According to your sample XML your first query `GetElementsByTagName("Dept Name")` would return an empty list, because there are no `<Dept Name>` elements... Apart from that, "Dept Name" is not a valid [QName](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QName), because it contains a space.

Comment: You cant add same key to dictionary

Comment: Thank you @Saadi. I got where i did mistakes. Now it runs perfectly.

Comment: Ok. Can I post my answer here? so that other viewers can know about it.

Comment: Yup, Please do post. It will help others as well as it will be helpful for me as well.